# Java 14 Language Specification Annotation Element Explanation - Possibly Typo?

Tags: java, annotations, jls

I have been struggling to understand the AnnotationTypeDeclaration in the Java Language Specification.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-9.html#jls-AnnotationTypeElementDeclaration

It reads:

```
AnnotationTypeElementDeclaration:
{AnnotationTypeElementModifier} UnannType Identifier ( ) [Dims] [DefaultValue]
```

According to this signature - a `Dims` expression may be placed between the `Identifier` and `defaultValue` and it seems to be legal to write an annotation element like this:

```java
package com.example.demo;

import java.lang.annotation.*;

@interface RequiredValue {
    String value() @Required[] default "default value";
}

@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.TYPE_USE})
@interface Required {

}
```

However, the compiler spit out the following error:

```
Incompatible types. Found: 'com.example.demo.Required', required: 'java.lang.String @com.example.demo.Required []'
```

After struggling to fix this error and here's what I had:

```java
package com.example.demo;

import java.lang.annotation.*;

@interface RequiredValue {
    Required value() @Required[] default @Required;
}

@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.TYPE_USE})
@interface Required {

}
```

As you can easily notice, I had to change the type of the `value()` element to `Required`. And now the code just compiles without errors.

It is also possible to omit the `defaultValue` definition.

```java
@interface RequiredValue {
    Required value() @Required[] default @Required;
    Required name() @Required[];
}
```

So - what's the point of having `Dims` (`@Required[]` in the example) and what's it for? I have not seen a line of Java code that practically looks like the above example. My question simply derives from the Java Language Specification and my curiosity to get to know the Java language better. I can think of several meanings of it but the syntax looks too strange to reason about them. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This compiles fine for me. The `@Required` in your first snippet is annotating the extra (array) dimension `[]`. The equivalent for a local array variable would be `int @Required [] ids;` or for a regular method `public int method() @Required []` (or `public int @Required [] method()`). Reflection doesn't allow you to access some of these, there used more for annotation processors and static analysis tools.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis So, `String value() [];` is functionally identical to `String[] value();`?

Comment: If it wasn't clear, your first snippet is an annotation element that has a return type of `String[]`, not `String`.

Comment: @VGR Yeah, that's right.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thank you for a quick answer! Please post your thought as an  answer so that I can accept it. Upvoting is not just enough ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So to summarize, the issue stems from the fact that the Java language per se is a replacement of the C++ language, hence retaining the C-style array syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You can have method headers such as `public int[] sort(int[] arr)` replaced with something like `public int sort(int arr[]) []`. The two are equivalent. Java has some weird alternative array syntax because it wanted C programmers to feel comfortable.

EDIT: According to @Sotirios Delimanolis, the @Required annotation applies to the array dimensions, so it's not quite the same as having a return type of `@Required String[]`

So your annotation is:

```
@interface RequiredValue {
    //Notice it's an array here              v
    String value() @Required[] default {"default value"};
}
```

is basically equivalent to this:

```
@interface RequiredValue {
    @Required String[] value() default {"default value"};
}
```

It's just a quirk of Java.

Comment: This isn't quite right. Depending on the `@Target` for `@Required`, in your second snippet, the annotation might be applying to the return type overall, to the method, but not to the array dimension itself, which is what the first snippet is doing.

Comment: I see. I don't see a dimension ElementType in the JavaDocs though. How does that work?

Comment: `TYPE_USE` will apply here iirc.